# What driver should I use for my USB camera?

Tags: ros, usb, camera, best-practices, camera-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see people using lots of different ROS packages to work with their USB webcams. What are the options?

- What cameras does the driver support?
- Which features does it have?
- What's the license?
- Where can I get it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9089/what-driver-should-i-use-for-my-usb-camera?/) by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) on ROS Answers with karma: 438 on 2011-02-16

Post score: 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most recent consumer webcams are compatible with the USB video class (UVC) device specification. ROS has several drivers that support these cameras as well as some non-UVC-compliant ones.

table#drivers tbody td { padding: 0.5em 0.25em 1em 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
table#drivers code { font-size: 90%; }

 
  PackageCapture MethodNotes
 
 
  
   libuvc_camera: `camera_node`
    https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc_ros.git
   
   libuvc (cross-platform)
   for USB Video Class-compliant cameras; BSD
  
  
   uvc_cam: `sender`
    [https://sail-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net
   /svnroot/sail-ros-pkg/trunk](https://sail-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/sail-ros-pkg/trunk)
   
   Video4Linux
   GPL
  
  
   uvc_cam: `sender`
    [https://github.com/ericperko/uvc_cam.git](https://github.com/ericperko/uvc_cam)
   
   Video4Linux
   Based on `uvc_cam`; reconfigurable parameters; calibration; GPL
  
  
   [uvc_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/uvc_camera): `camera_node`, `stereo_node`
    https://github.com/ktossell/camera_umd.git
   
   Video4Linux
   Based on `uvc_cam`; nodelets; calibration; GPL
  
  
   [gscam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gscam)[http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn
   /trunk/experimental/gscam](http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/gscam)
   
   GStreamer(cross-platform)
   GPL
  
  
   [usb_cam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/usb_cam)[https://bosch-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot
   /bosch-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/bosch_drivers](https://bosch-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/bosch-ros-pkg/trunk/stacks/bosch_drivers)
   
   Video4Linux
   BSD
  
  
   [gencam_cu](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gencam_cu)http://prairiedog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gencam_cu
   
   OpenCV(cross-platform)
   BSD
  
 


Also see [I Heart Robotics' comparison of USB camera drivers](http://www.iheartrobotics.com/2010/05/testing-ros-usb-camera-drivers.html).

---

Originally posted by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) with karma: 438 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 20

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-17**:
Ya... I saw it working there as well... why it doesn't work in reality... dunno.

**Comment by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) on 2011-02-16**:
The  tag worked in the preview!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best link for comparing all the ROS usb camera options

http://www.iheartrobotics.com/2010/05/testing-ros-usb-camera-drivers.html

---

Originally posted by [Eddit](https://answers.ros.org/users/1712/eddit/) with karma: 94 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eddit](https://answers.ros.org/users/1712/eddit/) on 2012-02-20**:
Why I am getting karma - when I am answering someone questions???!!!!!

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-02-20**:
What exactly are you asking here? Why are you not getting karma for your answers? Why are you losing karma when being downvoted? Why are you actually receiving karma for answering a question and getting upvotes?

**Comment by [Eddit](https://answers.ros.org/users/1712/eddit/) on 2012-02-21**:
Don't you think the way you answering my question is a bit offensive!!! I just friendly asked a question while I gave a short answer compared to the previous answer with the correct link to help somebody else I got minus sign " - " (- means MINUS in my comments above if you didn't understand).

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-21**:
Please calm down. Your original comment was unclear. There is no way to know why people voted your answer down, but don't take it personally.